# Azure service to perform heavy computation on data from a C# application

Tags: c#, json, azure

I'm looking for Azure service to perform heavy computation. I build a C# WPF application which will send JSON data to an Azure service to perform heavier computation. Returned data will be displayed by the app.

Which service should I choose? I like to add, that computation will happen on request, when user want to view data insights. So it's not live stream analysis.

Best regards!

Comment: I am sure you've read the azure docs regarding the [compute options](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/product-categories/compute/). Which ones did you have in mind and how can we help choosing one as it is really hard to give any advice based on the (lacks of) details you give? :-)

Comment: Mainly I need someting that can easily connect from C#. I was thinking about Batch.

Comment: How long does the computation take, and what kind are we dealing with?

Comment: Hi @KonradPsiukPG,
Can you provide more details on "performing heavier computation". What kind of computation and operation  you will be performing. This would really help me to provide you with better choice of Azure service.

Comment: Hi, sorry for lack of details. I’m looking to run data analysis on Machine PLC data. Data is delivered in json format. I want to provide service where user can get statistical performance data. As users have different workstation computers, easiest way is to process this data externally. I assume this way I can achieve relatively same performance regardless of user’s computer resources. Ideally I send data as string to Azure for processing and receive back results to display. I assume Azure function is not designed for this kind of purpose.

Comment: Per keviny's answer below, you can use an Azure Function with an HTTP trigger, sending your JSON via HTTP and receiving back the result in JSON to be formatted by the WPF frontend.  That said, Azure Functions can have various limitations on duration and speed depending on how they are configured.  So review the MS docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to have a function or series of functions that are running in Azure. How about using Azure Functions?

You can write the function in several different languages. You could trigger it via HTTP or even a message queue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/